# What is the impact of the breaking change in jQuery 3.5.0?

Tags: jquery

jQuery 3.5.0 was released on 10th of April 2020. It is a minor version but contains a security fix, which is described as a breaking change.

> The main change in this release is a security fix, and it’s possible you will need to change your own code to adapt. Here’s why: jQuery used a regex in its jQuery.htmlPrefilter method to ensure that all closing tags were XHTML-compliant when passed to methods. For example, this prefilter ensured that a call like `jQuery("<div class='hot' />")` is actually converted to `jQuery("<div class='hot'></div>")`.

Apprarently `jQuery.htmlPrefilter` is using now the string unchanged.

I have tried the example given above and I get the expect result in 3.5.0. What exactly has changed? What is the impact of this change and what should I adapt in my code if anything?

Here is the test I was running:

```js
console.log($("<div class='hot' />")[0].outerHTML == '<div class="hot"></div>')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have found an answer to my question on their official page. The [migration guide](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.5/) explains what the change means to developers and how it works.

The example from my question is unaffected because both the old and new jQuery code will produce the same result.

The difference can only be noticed when using multiple self-closing tags. For example:

```
$("<div/><span/>")
```

This code in jQuery < 3.5 would produce two separate HTML elements

```html
<div></div>
<span></span>
```

Since jQuery 3.5.0 the same code produces nested elements.

```html
<div><span></span></div>
```

Previously jQuery was using regular expression to expand self-closed tags:

```
/<(?!area|br|col|embed|hr|img|input|link|meta|param)(([a-z][^\/\0>\x20\t\r\n\f]*)[^>]*)\/>/gi
```

From version 3.5.0 it will now use identity function.

If your code used self-closing tags as described above you need to rewrite your code and test the functionality. When creating multiple HTML tags in a single jQuery call you need to be explicit if you want nested or contiguous elements.

Comment: Do we have any script to inspect for existing usage? Handling a large codebase, it'd be difficult to detect-trace-and-fix.